# How to delete a file on Linux using exec

Tags: php, bash, filesystems, escaping

I am trying to delete a previously created file called `a\`.

I tried to use:

1)

```
rm -rf a\\
```

2)

```
rm -rf a\\/
```

but both are not working. I tried to login to the terminal but I was unable to delete. I wrote `a` and then clicked `tab` and it shows `a\\/` but it stills not working. Neither from terminal. I get:

```
 sudo rm -rf a\\/
 rm: cannot remove `a\\': Operation not permitted
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Type `a` and press `TAB` key - let the shell do it for you.

Comment: "Operation not permitted" means you don't have permission to delete the file. Do it as root or the user who owns the file.

Comment: hsz please read the question. I pushed tab button.

Comment: Wooble please check the command. I am using sudo!

Comment: I tested it locally and both `rm 'a\'` and "rm a\\" work for me.

Comment: el.atomo: yes. I tried as root as well.

Comment: I logged in as root. And I cannot remove it

Comment: First find out what the definite file-name is (un-escaped) and share it with your question.

Comment: what is wrong with `unlink(2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `exec("rm -rf a\\\\");` in your php code.

Php uses `\\` to escape `\` and system uses the same, so you need to escape `\` twice

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your using Ubuntu due to sudo?

Firstly make sure you are in the same directory as the file you are trying to delete, do this with:

```
print(getcwd());
```

Secondly try changing the owner of file your are trying to delete to www-data (or apache depending on your server) and then see if you can delete the file from the php script.

If this works then the problem you have is permission related.

There are a number of ways to solve this problem.

1. Make sure the files your are deleting are owned by the web server process (most secure).
2. Give the files 777 permissions so any user can delete them.
3. Add the web server user to sudoers (/etc/sudoers) (least secure)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to specify the full path of the file using either `/path/to/file` or `./a\\`. The escape stuff have been explained already.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure what you have permission for delete
2. Create folder:

   `mkdir -m777 myFolder;`
3. Delete file from php code:

   `$file = escapeshellarg("/root/myFolder/1.txt");`
   `$del = shell_exec("rm -rf $file");`